# Web Deployment Projects, Web Application Projects and Team Build 2008

Tags: visual-studio, web-deployment-project, tfsbuild

I've switched from a Website Project to a WAP (Web Application project).

The WDP (Web Deployment Project) is used to set  and potentially in the future make other web.config changes.

However I notice that the team build is building everything twice, once on behalf of the solution file and then again because of the WDP. Any idea how I can stop this from happening?

Or is there a way to replace out the web deployment project altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes.

You can stop TFS Build from building everything twice by following these steps:

1. Open the configuration manager (open your solution and select **Configuration Manager** from the top-level Build menu).
2. Expand the drop down list for Active solution configuration and select **New**.
3. Enter a name for your new solution configuration and select an existing configuration to copy settings from and click **OK**.
4. In the Configuration Manager, uncheck the checkboxes in the **Build** column for all of the projects except the deployment project and click **Close**.
5. Edit your TFSBuild.proj file's **ConfigurationToBuild** ItemGroup by adding your new configuration:

       
         Foo
         Any CPU

   Where *Foo* is the name of the new configuration you just defined.

---

For Visual Studio 2010, the ASP.NET team has partnered with the IIS team to deliver an integrated web application packaging and deployment solution built on the [Web Deployment Tool][1]. It more or less replaces web deployment projects and you can use it with VS/TFS 2008 via its [command line interface][2]. I have a blog post covering the basic scenario here:

[Building a Simple Web Site with VSTS/TFS 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/jimlamb/archive/2009/04/16/building-a-simple-web-site-with-vsts-tfs-2008.aspx).

Comment: Good answer, I actually ended up just removing the website deployment project, it was faster and there was pretty much no need for it.